# How to change a list which contains Longitude/Latitude to a list which contains Latitude/Longitude - Django?

Tags: django

I searched for hours on the internet to find a solution but without success. The polygons are displayed on the map but not in their real position because the longitude is diplayed as latitude and the latitude as longitude. Please, is there a solution to change the position of latitude and longitude in the list? Please, see printed result below.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField, MultiPointField, MultiPolygonField

class BurnedArea(models.Model):
    firedate = models.DateField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    place_name = models.IntegerField()
    province = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    yearseason = models.FloatField()
    geom = MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def lat_lng(self):
        return list(getattr(self.geom, 'coords', [] ) [::-1] )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.place_name)
```

views.py:

```
def viewer(request):

    resultba = []
    pol2 = 0,0

    areas = BurnedArea.objects.all()

    for ba in areas:
        balon = str(ba.lat_lng)
        pol = balon.replace("(", "[")
        pol2 = pol.replace(")", "]")
        print(pol2)
        resultba.append({'pol2':pol2})
    context = {
    'resultba':resultba,
    {
    return render(request, 'app_web/viewer.html', context)
```

printed result :

```
[[[[8.6065550282249, 36.8027181091122], [8.60768086453233, 36.8020611860536], [8.60746659932254, 36.8016392882169], [8.60734205760659, 36.8011823076919], [8.60600897419624, 36.8016267925537], [8.6064362319159, 36.8019699263144], [8.6065550282249, 36.8027181091122]],]]
```

but I want to have it like this :

```
[[[[36.8027181091122, 8.6065550282249], [36.8020611860536, 8.60768086453233], [36.8016392882169,8.60746659932254], [36.8011823076919, 8.60734205760659], [36.8016267925537, 8.60600897419624], [36.8019699263144, 8.6064362319159], [36.8027181091122, 8.6065550282249]],]]
```

viewer.html:

```
<section class="mapid" id="mapid" ></section>
<script>
    {% for area in resultba %}
    L.polygon([{{area.pol2}}], {color: 'blue'}).addTo(map);
    {% endfor %}
</script>
```